# TypeScript - Use function parameter type as an argument of return type (without generics)?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
enum Dimension {
  Margin = 'margin',
  Padding = 'padding',
  Content = 'content',
};

enum MarginStyleKey {
  Top = 'margin-top',
  Left = 'margin-left',
  Bottom = 'margin-bottom',
  Right = 'margin-right',
}

enum PaddingStyleKey {
  Top = 'padding-top',
  Left = 'padding-left',
  Bottom = 'padding-bottom',
  Right = 'padding-right',
}

enum ContentStyleKey {
  Width = 'width',
  Height = 'height',
}

type DimensionStyleKeys = {
  [Dimension.Margin]: MarginStyleKey;
  [Dimension.Padding]: PaddingStyleKey;
  [Dimension.Content]: ContentStyleKey;
}

type DimensionStyles <T extends Dimension> = {
  [styleKey in DimensionStyleKeys[T]]: string;
}

type GetDimension = (dimension: Dimension) => DimensionStyles<dimension>
```

So what I would like at the end, to the type of the function depending on the parameter (because  the type of the function parameter, and type of the keys of `DimensionStyleKeys` are common), it can automatically decide the return type of the function.

Of course

`type GetDimension <T extends Dimension> = (dimension: T) => DimensionStyles<T>`

would solve the problem, but I can't see any reason why it couldn't work without using generic in the function type.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to narrow the type to the argument it is the only way to use generics, any other way will be just equal `DinemsionStyles<Dimension>`. Inferring argument works only with generic types.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would happen "automatically"?  If `dimension` is of type `Dimension`, a union type, then the best you can do with a non-generic function is say that it will return a union of output types.  If you want to track which member of the union is passed in, you either need generics or overloads.  The overload answer looks like `type GetDimension = { [D in Dimension]: (a: (d: D) => DimensionStyles<D>) => void }[Dimension] extends (a: infer U) => void ? U : never;`, but the generic is less annoying to use. If you elaborate maybe I can make an answer.  Good luck.